# Stationary solution multidimensional Fokker-Planck equation/PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stationary-processes

Does anyone have a clever method for finding the solution to this PDE?
$$0=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left((Ax+C(x-y))p(x,y)\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left((By+C(y-x))p(x,y)\right)+D\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+2E\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}\right]p(x,y)$$
for $p(x,y)$ given that $A,B,C,D,E$ are all positive constants with $0<E<1$. It is trivial for $E=0$ but I don't know how to deal with the cross derivative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a linear Fokker-Planck equation, so the solution is a Gaussian.
The only parameters, the averages (which are zeros in this case) and variances, can be found by brute force, but the following method [see for example van Kampen, page 212](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0444529659) is somewhat easier.

We will change the notation a bit for convenience
$$
\sum_{i,j=1}^2 \frac{ \partial }{ \partial x_i } (A_{ij} x_j P) + B_{ij} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} P = 0.
\qquad (1)
$$

Let us first compute the Fourier transform (characteristic function)
$$
G(k_1, k_2) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(x_1, x_2) \, \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^2 i k_i x_i\right) \, dx_1 \, dx_2.
$$
Now by multiplying $\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^2 i k_i x_i\right)$ and integrating by parts, we get
$$
-\sum_{i,j=1}^2 k_i A_{ij} \frac{ \partial G } { \partial k_j }
-k_i \, k_j \, B_{ij} \, G = 0.
$$
At this point, we can impose that the generating function is Gaussian, and
$$
\log G(k_1, k_2) = -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j=1}^2 k_i \Xi_{ij} k_j,
$$
where $\Xi_{ij}$ is the symmetric covariance matrix of $\operatorname{cov}(x_i, x_j)$. This quadratic form can also be readily shown by using the method of characteristics.
Thus
$$
\sum_{i,j,l=1}^2 k_i \, A_{ij} \, \Xi_{jl} \, k_l = \sum_{i,l} k_i \, B_{il} \, k_l.
$$
Since this equation holds for all values of $k_1$ and $k_2$, and $B_{ij}$ is symmetric, we must have
$$
\sum_{j = 1}^2 A_{ij} \Xi_{jl} + \Xi_{ij} A_{lj} = 2 \, B_{il}.
$$
Or in matrix form
$$
\mathbf{ A \Xi}  + \mathbf{\Xi A}^T = 2 \, \mathbf B.
\qquad (2)
$$
Now this is the [Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation), and the solution (the integral form) is
$$
\mathbf \Xi = 2 \int_0^\infty \exp(-\mathbf A \, t) \, \mathbf B \, \exp(-\mathbf A^T \, t) \, dt.
\qquad (3)
$$
In our case, this expression converges because $\mathbf A$ is positive-definite ($\operatorname{tr}\mathbf A = A + B + 2 C > 0$, and $\operatorname{det}\mathbf A = AB+BC+CA > 0$).  And we can verify it directly
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf {A \Xi + \Xi A}^T
&= -2\int_0^\infty
\left[ 
\frac{d}{dt} \left[\exp(-\mathbf A t) \right]\, \mathbf B \, \exp(-\mathbf A^T t)
+
\exp(-\mathbf A t) \, \mathbf B \, \frac{d}{dt}  \exp(-\mathbf A^T t)
\right] \, dt
\\
&=
-2\exp(-\mathbf A t) \, \mathbf B \, \exp(-\mathbf A^T t) \Bigg|_0^\infty
= 2 \, \mathbf B.
\end{aligned}
$$

In summary, the distribution is a two-dimensional Gaussian,
$$
P(\mathbf x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{\operatorname{det} \mathbf \Xi}}
\exp\left( - \frac{1}{2} \mathbf x \mathbf \Xi^{-1} \mathbf x^T \right).
$$
with the covariance matrix $\mathbf \Xi$ given by (3).

---

Edit.  There is a simpler solution. Since the solution is a Gaussian centered at zero, we only need to determine the covariant matrix, which can done as follows.

Multiplying (1) by $x_r x_s$ and integrating over $dx_1 dx_2$, we get
$$
-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty
\left[
\sum_{j=1}^2 \left( x_s A_{rj}x_j + x_r A_{sj} x_j \right)
+(B_{rs} + B_{sr}) \right]\, P \, dx_1 \, dx_2 = 0.
$$
Since $\mathbf B$ is symmetric, this means
$$
\sum_{j=1}^2
\left[
A_{rj} \operatorname{cov}(x_j, x_s) + \operatorname{cov}(x_r, x_j) A_{sj}
\right]
+ 2 B_{rs}  = 0,
$$
which is just the component form as (2).  Then the solution (3) follows.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks.

Comment: @user3353819. My pleasure, glad it helps. :-)